# Predicting a class of a an image from google images(bag) using a model that is trained using fashion mnist dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, keras, tf.keras

I am trying to do Image Recognition in Python with TensorFlow and Keras.I'm only beginning with keras and machine learning. I have trained the model using fashion MNIST dataset. I am now trying to predict this model by using an external image from google images. I am using an image of a bag. Please see below

[image]

I understand I need to load this new image, force it to be grayscale format, and force the size to be 28×28 pixels as this is how my training images are while training the model. grayscale and 28 * 28.

Hence, I followed some blogs and used below code to the same.

```
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

img_path = 'data/bag2.jpg'

img = image.load_img(img_path,grayscale=True,target_size=(28, 28))
img_tensor = image.img_to_array(img)
img_tensor = numpy.expand_dims(img_tensor, axis=0)
img_tensor /= 255.
pyplot.imshow(img_tensor[0])
pyplot.show()
print(img_tensor.shape)
```

The output of the above code is as below

[image]

Why the background is yellow and image is not gray? Is this correct? Based on what I understand , the background should be black and image should be gray.

while I trying to predict this image using below code, I get output as zero

```
pred = model.predict(img_tensor.reshape(-1,28, 28, 1))
print(pred.argmax())
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the point of `gray_img` if you never use it? Also some pieces of your code are redondant, please edit your question

Comment: @RandomGuy, I had initially tried loading the gray_img instead of img directly. However, it gave me an error as TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not numpy.ndarray. I was not able to fix it and hence tried img = image.load_img(img_path, grayscale=True,target_size=(28, 28)) which worked. Did not comment out removed the code that was not working. I have edited my code in the question now. Please let me know how do I get gray image as that what I need to use while predicting.

Comment: According to the [tensorflow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/load_img), `grayscale` is deprecated. Try using `img = image.load_img(img_path,color_mode='grayscale',target_size=(28, 28))` instead. Also, `pred = model.predict(img_tensor)` should work, no need to reshape your array.

Comment: @RandomGuy, thanks for your quick response. I looked at the documentation and tried using img = image.load_img(img_path,color_mode='grayscale',target_size=(28, 28)). It gives me same yellow background image as I provided in my questions. Not sure what's wrong.

Comment: Mmmh, this may be an error from `load_image` then... Could you please try with `img_tensor = cv2.imread(img_path , cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)` please? And then, `img_tensor = numpy.expand_dims(img_tensor, axis=0)` and so on

Comment: That background is something about matplotlib's default. You need to specify `cmap = pyplot.cm.gray` when plotting the image. Default is `viridis`.

Comment: it worked now where I added pyplot.imshow(img_tensor[0], cmap='gray').  Thanks for all the inputs.

Comment: @Frightera, it worked as I mentioned in my comment above. Thanks again. Could you please tell me if I use virdis which color is 0 and 255? Like in grayscale 255 is black and 0 is white. I have seen viridis being used while visualizing intermediate activation in deep learning.

Answer (score 1):

The above error worked by using below code

from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

```
img_path = 'data/bag5.jpg'
img = image.load_img(img_path,color_mode='grayscale',target_size=(28, 28))
img_tensor = image.img_to_array(img)
img_tensor = numpy.expand_dims(img_tensor, axis=0)
img_tensor /= 255.

pyplot.imshow(img_tensor[0], cmap='gray')
pyplot.show()
print(img_tensor.shape)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are plotting with pyplot.imshow(), if you mention cmap='gray' then you can see grayscale images. In above code yellow background is default behaviour of imshow function.

Now if you use above mentioned solution and don't get correct results then try to get similar image as that of the dataset. Fashion MNIST dataset has images - 28x28 pixels, grayscale i.e. with black background and cloth item at foreground. The image you read

```
img = image.load_img(img_path,grayscale=True,target_size=(28, 28))
```

is grayscale but with white background. So you can use -

```
img = ImageOps.invert(img)
```

Now try to plot this with cmap='gray' and do prediction. If your model is trained with a reasonable accuracy you'll get correct results, almost for many images.